# draw the directed graph of the reflexive closure

Tags: relations, directed-graphs

draw the directed graph of the reflexive closure of the relations with the directed graph shown

[image]

Comment: You have asked a question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3424785/let-r-be-a-relation-on-the-set-of-integers) on reflexive closure before. Perhaps it is time for you to revisit the definition and improve your understanding. Hint: think what "edges" (loops) you need to "add" to make the new relation reflexive.

Comment: I didn't understand the example in the book, that's why I set the example here

Answer (score 0):

The reflexive closure is given by the relation plus all the directed edges are needed to make the new relation reflexive. Hence we add the loops on $b$, $c$, and $d$ and obtain the following:

[image]